# How to check my In-app billing product is already purchased in app by user?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

i need to check when app start then the In-App product is already purchase by user or not.

how to check user is already purchase specify app product ?

its also working when app uninstall and re-install app , this functionality provide by android api or not ?

can anyone suggest me which step follow for this so user not again purchased product and we check in app side its purchased then we give some features to users in app..

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you need a database to persist the orders. Second of all, when the user install the your app. You have to issue a RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS what the user has bought and insert the result into the local database. you can read more in this link. http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html

search for the keyword RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS

Comment: I Have used following code sample to do in app billing http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/ but when i called restoreTransactionInformation(Long nonce) method given in the code sample, m not able to get the item that are already purchase..i am not able to figure out from where it return the product-id that are already purchased

Comment: I am planning to save this info in memory instead of database. Will this have any problems?