# In-app billing. How to store information that user has paid?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play

There was a similar subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462641/how-to-check-my-in-app-billing-product-is-already-purchased-in-app-by-user)

Okay. We can find out about user's purchase using RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS request to Google Play.
But. It is written in documentation that
" You should use the RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS request type only when your application is installed for the first time on a device or when your application has been removed from a device and reinstalled."
Why not after every start? 
It looks comfortable and possible to query Google Play every time when the app starts.

Otherewise

1) I should store information about payment on my WEB server

2) Or I should save this info to sdcard. The record should be secure, including
device ID, so that copy on another device will not work

So. Which way is better?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest:

3) Use the in-app Shared-Preferences Class or SQLite Database

(Check this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Encryption is always good, but this way the data is so to say attached to your application and can usually not be accessed by other apps.

Comment: Why not. However Shared Preferences and DB can be edited on a rooted phone. Hence, you must ensure that the information about payment is signed in a way that cannot be imitated.

Comment: That's why I said 'Encryption is always good' and 'can usually not' ;) But this way the data is bound to your application.

Comment: Yes, really. Shared-Preferences looks good, if it is impossible to read it from another app or to hack somehow. Especially if the data will not expire after turning the device off. I think the algorithm is easy. 1) First check data in Shared-Preferences. 2) If not found then check purchase on Google Play. I think that no need of SQLite Database for 2-5 numbers. Thanks.

Comment: Please consider: Everything can be hacked and on rooted devices you won't have the chance to hide anything. So always take care of a "child safety lock".
Offtopic: Using SharedPreferences, you can also set default values for initialisation, so you can create a variable "firstRun = true" which will be set to false by your application and then stay false as long as your app keeps installed.